# saving not validating properties

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

MyI have strange requirement in my project. I must using validator on the field which is binding to the view and has OnPropertyChange method in setter. This is done:

```
public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private const int MyLength = 17;

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var valueString = (string)value;
        if (valueString != null && valueString.Length == MyLength)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Invalid value");
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
< Binding Path="Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <validationRules:MyValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

This work correctly but that requirement is fact that i must saving not validating value in db. The validator should only do red background.

I just want to call setter of this property when value is not validating

EDIT

I want to call setter of my property with this validation rule, when its length is not equal to 17 (MyLength).

Comment: While I understand that English may not be your first language, I'd try to edit your question to make it clearer, because it is not very clear at the moment.

Comment: I edited it. Now when the length is not 17 the setter isn't call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in different way. I implement IDataErrorInfo interface and implement its members:

```
public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            return Validate(columnName);
        }
    }

    public string Error { get; private set; }

    public string Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        string error = null;
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "Value":
                if (_value.Length != 17)
                    error = "Invalid value";
                break;
        }

        Error = error;
        return error;
    }
```

and in binding, set flag:

```
ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
```

Now it's working as I wanted.